# ImageView's size can't adapt with image from net in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, imageview, adapter

[image: Image File]

I have a question , it make me tired whole day.
Why `ImageView`'s background is show when load net picture into `ImageView` in `GridView`? `ImageView`'s size can't wrap_content.

How could I fix it? Make `ImageView`'s size adapt picture size (don't change the piacture size)
thanks advance.

A .Main XML

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_listview"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:divider="@color/colorAlpha"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selected"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/gridview_item_selected"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</GridView>
```

B.GridView Item XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="1dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_gridview"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_gridview"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="#00ffff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

C.GridView adapter extends BaseAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GridViewHolder gridViewHolder = new GridViewHolder();
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    if (convertView == null ) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item , null) ;
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_gridview);
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_gridview);
        gridViewHolder.setImageView(imageView);
        gridViewHolder.setTextView(textView);
        convertView.setTag(gridViewHolder);
    }else {
        gridViewHolder = (GridViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://img1.cache.netease.com/catchpic/A/A8/A86B03AE11945B98D0AE0A98480D28CE.jpg").into(gridViewHolder.getImageView());
    gridViewHolder.getTextView().setText(dataList.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

D.Activity code

```
    dataList = GetData.getData();
    GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(GridView.this , dataList);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    gridView.setNumColumns(3);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(5);
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing(10);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String url = "this is " + position ;
            startActivity(new Intent(GridView.this , ClickActivity.class).putExtra("url" ,url));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `android:adjustViewBounds` attribute on your `ImageView` to `true` in your layout XML.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_gridview"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) on `android:adjustViewBounds`:

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to
>   preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.